# Stats of Riven's Wind Slash

Tags: league-of-legends

`Wind Slash` is the ranged area damage (cone in front) spell that Riven can use once she activates her R. I've read that it is similar to Garen's `Demacian Justice`, i.e. it deals more damage to lower health targets.

I have not found good information on the actual base stats & scaling for Wind Slash, since actual tooltips etc. are all related to the base AD & range boosts for her R.

- What are the actual numbers, if possible with comparison to Garen's ultimate?
- How do I effectively use Wind Slash in 1v1s and team fights?

Comment: Darius' `Noxian Guillotine` doesn't actually deal more damage to lower health targets; rather, it interacts with his passive. For each stack of `Hemmorhage`, `Noxian Guillotine` deals 20% bonus damage (up to 100% bonus damage). If it scaled with missing health, it'd be pretty powerful, considering it's true damage!

Comment: @Yves: Thanks, I had some wrong impression of Darius' R - updated the question to correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Riven)

**Wind Slash**:     Riven can activate the ability to emit a shockwave in a long cone in front of her that deals physical damage to all units hit based on their missing health.

```
No cost
Range: 900
Missile Speed: 2200
```

> Minimum Physical Damage: 80 / 120 / 160 (**+0.6** per bonus attack damage)
>
> Maximum Physical Damage (25% health or lower): 240 / 360 / 480 (+1.8
> per bonus attack damage)

Since this has linear scaling, this means that the minimum damage (before reduction from armor) occurs at 100% health, the maximum is at 25% or below, with an increase of 300% (over the base ability) at this optimal usage.

This means that (give or take) you get a 4% increase in damage per 1% missing health (though, again, it's linear, not a step function).

This scaling is different from both Garen (who gets bonus damage per missing health **point**) and Lee Sin (who gets bonus damage based on a percentage of the missing health).

Comment: Ty, overlooked the info in wikia :). Any tips or tricks on using it effectively? (besides the obvious, kill fleeing low hp enemy)

Comment: @Alok Just remember that you don't have to use it immediately. Using your ult is a huge AD steroid for Riven, and adds range to her abilities too. Once you ult, you'll hit harder, chase better, and tank better (thanks to E scaling!), so make sure to pop it at the beginning of the fight, not at the end!